# Foreach and SqlConnection Using Statement

Tags: c#, sql, optimization, foreach

I'm trying to figure out which is more efficient to run. I have a `foreach` of tables and I'm wondering if it should be outside of my using or inside of it. Examples below.

the `using (SqlConnection)` inside of the `foreach`:

```
foreach (string tableName in desiredTables)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cloudConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        string query = string.Format("SELECT id, active, createdon, modifiedon FROM {0}", tableName);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            try
            {
                dAdapter.Fill(dSet, tableName);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Versus the `foreach` inside of the `using (SqlConnection)`:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cloudConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    foreach (string tableName in desiredTables)
    {

        string query = string.Format("SELECT id, active, createdon, modifiedon FROM {0}", tableName);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            try
            {
                dAdapter.Fill(dSet, tableName);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to optimize this for a faster pull from the DB and I'm not sure which way is recommended/better. Advice would be great.

Comment: Which is faster?  Try measuring each version a million times each.

Comment: Is this a repeating task, or a rarely used operation?

Comment: FYI, `catch { throw; }` is pointless - may as well not even have a `catch` blocxk (or a `try` either in this case).

Comment: Really?   As fast as open connection from a pool why do is multiple times.   As for that why are you looping on using SqlCommand?  Why are you bring down one table at a time rather than a DataSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to try it and measure it to be certain, but I doubt you'll see a huge difference either way.  Connections are pooled by .NET, so creating them in a loop (I'm assuming you just have a handful of tables, not several hundred) should not be a significant bottleneck.  You'll likely spend a LOT more time in network I/O and actually populating the DataSet (which *does* have a lot of overhead).

Bottom line - fine one way that works (so you have something to revert back to) and try it multiple ways and see if one method makes a significant difference to the application *overall*.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, Open and Close a database connection multiple times in a network environment can be expensive (connection data travels thru your network several rounds, the C# CLR has to allocate and free resource several times, the Garbage Collection has more works to do later...), so you should try to reuse your database connection by putting it outside the loop.

Comment: It's not as bad as you make it sound.  Database connections are pooled by .NET, so creating them is typically not a very expensive process (relative to the time spent in network I/O st least).  It;s generally _worse_ to keep a single connection open for long periods of time.

Comment: Well, at least the case that we call Open() and Close() pair one time outside the loop versus we call it multiple times in a loop are different. Call it one time versus a few hundreds of times, even with the help of .NET connection pool, the time duration spent in the CPU are quite different. You can easily write a simple loop to verify the fact.

Comment: .NET will try to reuse your pooled connection whenever possible, but it doesn't mean that this will happen all the time and with no cost.
When we use the code in a component of a heavy web site, if we Close() then Open() the connection repeatedly, we may not get the same connection that we opened before. What will happen if right after we close it, someone take it and suddenly all available connections are in used? Our Open() method have to wait until other release the resource or time-out happens. So, why not reuse the connection explicitly FOR THE LOOP only to avoid this situation?